# React - rerender after content becomes visible

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a React (hooks) component inside an Accordion (`<details>` element).

The component makes some assumptions about `offsetWidth` for some child elements being available, but as the accordion is closed, the component is not visible and these Refs have an offsetWidth of 0.

I need to re-render the component, after the accordion is open and the component itself becomes visible.

I am trying passing the state of the accordion (open/closed) down to the component to trigger a render when this changes, but useEffect is run before the browser draws the component, so width is still 0 even if accordion state is open.

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Could you add some code?

Answer (score 1):

Well actually `useEffect` is called after the component re-render. So that is probably not your problem.

I suggest using the state for dynamically adding a class with `display: none` and removing it. instead of changing its width to zero

Comment: the width it's 0 because the "body" of the accordion (and thus the component) is not displayed. It's a native <details> element, not sure how it internally works.

Comment: you are right... from react documentation https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#example-using-hooks _ React guarantees the DOM has been updated by the time it runs the effects._

Comment: glad I could help